# DependencyProperty on custom control not binding?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a custom control with a label on it. This control has a property `Label` like this:

```
public string Label
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
    set
    {
        label.Text = value; 
        SetValue(LabelProperty, value);
    }
}

public static DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(SuperButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Note, label with small l is an internal textblock. SuperButton is the name of the control.

Then I have this simple object:

```
class Student  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged( new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

So then I bind with this XAML:

```
<UIFragments:SuperButton Margin="531,354,555,367" Label="{Binding Name}"></UIFragments:SuperButton>
```

And then I have this in the same page as the button instance

```
    Student s = new Student { Name = "John Smith" };
        DataContext = s;
```

I have tried setting the control's datacontext to itself but nothing is working. Setting the Label to a string works.

If I use the data binding the set{} block is never fired...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML doesn't call your Setter method, as is pointed out [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The WPF XAML processor uses property system methods for dependency
>   properties when loading binary XAML and processing attributes that are
>   dependency properties. This effectively bypasses the property
>   wrappers. When you implement custom dependency properties, you must
>   account for this behavior and should avoid placing any other code in
>   your property wrapper other than the property system methods GetValue
>   and SetValue.

What you need to do is register a callback method that fires whenever the dependency property changes:

```
public static DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Label", 
    typeof(string), 
    typeof(SuperButton), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback)
);
```

Note the `PropertyChangedCallback` in the last line! This method is implemented as follows:

```
private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    SuperButton userControl = ((SuperButton)dependencyObject);
    userControl.label.Text = (string) args.NewValue;
}
```

The dependency property's getter and setter now can be reduced to:

```
public string Label
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
}
```

Now whenever the `Label` property is changed, e.g. through binding it in your page, `PropertyChangedCallback` is called and that passes the text to your actual label!

Comment: I have tried this, but the callback only seems to get called when I set the property to a string - if I bind to it, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the DependencyProperty's default value (the first argument of `new PropertyMetadata(...)`) and the *value* of the variable you're binding to - if both are the same, the callback won't execute.

Comment: Thanks alot for the feedback! Turns out I had the datacontext in my user control's constructor set to 'this'. My silly mistake! Thanks again